# Capture Image of Arbitrary Space or Desktop

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

When you enter mission control, you are shown thumbnails of all your spaces / desktops:

[image: Mission Control Thumbnails]

I was wondering if it is possible to programmatically acquire these images within an OSX application -- preferably at full resolution.